# Converting to Morse Code in Ada

Tags: arrays, string, loops, ada

I posted the other day here because I was confused behind the syntax of Fortran and got an answer that helped a lot. But now I'm stuck in the same pickle, but with Ada this time.

Below is the gist of my program. I'm trying to read a sentence from the user and convert each character in it into morse code.

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Strings;
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded;
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded;
with Ada.Command_Line;
use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure MorseCode is
    tempSentence : array(1 .. 20) of string;
    last : Integer;
    size : Integer;
    i : Integer;
begin

Put("Enter the size of your sentence: ");
Get(size);
Put("Enter the sentence you would like to convert to morse code: ");
Get_Line(tempSentence, last);
Put_Line(tempSentence);

While_Loop :
while i < size loop

if tempSentence(i .. i) = 'A' or tempSentence(i) = 'a' then
    Put(".- ");
elsif tempSentence(i .. i) = 'B' or tempSentence(i) = 'b' then
    Put("-... ");
elsif tempSentence(i) = 'C' or tempSentence(i) = 'c' then
    Put("-.-. ");
end if;
end loop While_Loop;

end;
```

Comment: ...And the problem is?

Comment: You got a -1 to your Fortran question because it did lack any evidence of research on your side. Just because some nice user fixed everything for you does not mean that this is acceptable behavior. And now you're doing this again. Look at the error messages of your compiler, try to fix them (if you can't make sense of them, use the internet), and *then*, if you get stuck on a certain error, you may ask about it on SO.

Answer (score 0):

I probably shouldn't, but the problems here go far beyond simple syntax errors so here's a few pointers to a more Ada-like approach.

Words in bold are worth reading about in more detail in a good Ada book.

First, stop thinking at such a low level. **Strings** are arrays of characters, and **arrays** in Ada offer facilities such as array **attributes** to make programming simpler - and especially program maintenance.

Arrays are fixed in length when you create them, but that length doesn't have to be determined until then. So you can **declare** an array and initialise it with a function call - it takes its size from the result of the function call.

Use this facility and eliminate `size` as a separate thing altogether.

When the declare block ends, the array goes out of scope, so it's freed automatically, and if it's in a loop, the function call can return a different size string, so the array bounds can be different each time - to problem.

We need to loop over all characters in the array, but we don't know its size ... so just ask it, for example via its **range** attribute.

And rather than writing every test twice, use a function from the `Ada.Characters.Handling` **package** to ensure we only hve to deal with lower case.

Also, **if** statements are a poor choice for this task, a **case** statement is simpler and shorter - I've shown both below

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
use  Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Characters.Handling;


procedure MorseCode is

begin
   Put("Enter the sentence you would like to convert to morse code: ");

   declare
      Sentence : String := Get_Line;
   begin
      Put_Line(Sentence);

      for i in Sentence'range loop

         if Ada.Characters.Handling.To_Lower(Sentence(i)) = 'a' then
            Put(".- ");
         -- elsif etc ... not very nice
         end if;

         case Ada.Characters.Handling.To_Lower(Sentence(i)) is
         when 'b' => Put("-...");
         when 'c' => Put("-.-.");
         when others => null;
         end case;

      end loop;
   end;
end;
```

There are also **bounded** and **unbounded** strings which you don't need in this simple example. They are a little tedious to use sometimes, you need type conversions between them and plain Strings.

Comment: I would seriously consider making an array of bounded or unbounded strings containing all the Morse code translations. That array should be indexed by the corresponding character value so that the response is an array lookup and not a very long case statement.

Comment: I agree. I sketched that out too, but decided against adding it to the answer.